# Markdown support suddenly broken (Apple Shortcuts MacOS) after Xcode uninstall

Tags: macos, markdown, macos-ventura, sirishortcuts, xcode-command-line-tools

I recently installed the newest version of MacOS and also uninstalled Xcode and its CLI tools. Because the uninstallation process was quite messy (I had to alter zsh profile and reinstall Python since that stopped working as well) I am not sure if I maybe broke something myself. Since then (unfortunately I cannot pinpoint wether it was right after the update or after I uninstalled Xcode) I cannot open Markdown files in Apple Shortcuts. I have attached a screenshot of an example Shortcut which works on iOS but doesn't on my Mac (see fig. 01). Another side effect is that when I use QuickLook (»space« key) on .md files, instead of previewing the raw text of that file I only get the file icon (see fig. 02)

**fig. 01**
[image: example shortcut, content of test.md is »This is a test if md files can still be read using shortcuts.«]

**fig. 02**
[image: how QuickLook preview looks now for .md]
[image: how QuickLook looks for .txt files (displaying the raw text content)]

**System**
Intel-based MacBook Pro (2019)
Running MacOS Ventura (13.6)

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

**What I already tried**

*Reinstall Xcode CLI tools*
I tried to reinstall the cli tools using `xcode-select --install`. This did not help which is why I uninstalled them again.

*Reinstall MacOS Ventura using the Recovery Tool*
I did a full OS reinstall (but preserving my data since I currently do not have to access to my backup drive). This also did not help.

When I can access my backup drive again, I will try a full reset including data removal. If you have any suggestions on how to increase the chance of that helping fell free to include them here as well.

Comment: I am using Ventura 13.5.2 and Xcode 15. If I quicklook a markdown document I get what you see in your last screenshot. Do you expect to see the file rendered as markdown? Have you tried changing what .md files pen with in the Get Info pane? It looks like your markdown documents are opening with Visual Studio?

Comment: No I wasn’t expecting rendered markdown but the raw text content showing up like it does for the txt file. My main issue however is that Shortcuts lost the ability to open .md files since I am using that for time tracking in my obsidian vault.

Comment: That Quicklook screenshot of textfile.txt appears normal. macOS and TextEdit should be treating txt and md files as plain text. What happens you run the shortcut?

Comment: What you see in the first screenshot. It just opens the file the same quick look would and if creating a text from input just outputting the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reinstall of the Xcode App fixed the problem.**

This morning I had the opportunity to try and see the default behavior on a MacBook (ARM-based) where Xcode had never been installed before. Since that behaved the same as I what I described in my question, I figured it had to be something that is only installed with Xcode. After I reinstalled the IDE and set the dev mode to macOS (which installed some extra dependencies), I can confirm that both the quick look feature and my shortcut work as they did before. If anyone knows more details about what dependency might be responsible I am grateful for any more insights since I do not really need it for anything else. I will mark this thread as answered though since for now this is working fine.